# Full Calendar Initial events don't refresh when event is updated or deleted

Tags: reactjs, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Here's my Calendar setup, Unfortunately I cannot produce a runnable demo because my app uses Fetch from API, Redux and many other components to work. But I will try my best to explain everything that is happening.

Initially when my Calendar component loads, I use hooks to fetch data and populate it with "Events" prop or even "EventSource" Works, but not "InitialEvents".. SO I use either Events or EventSource, both are not an issue.

The only problem I have left is when a user clicks an event, I capture the arguments of that event and display a modal so that users can edit or delete an event.

This process works perfectly except for when there is an initial fetch, the loaded events do not delete or update. when the button is clicked, it goes to the server and deletes it but the calendar component itself does not refresh.
This happens only with the initial load, if I create or update new events after this, everything works flawlessly.

So how do I refetch events or keep the calendar in sync with the server?

**Code for remove event** this function works perfectly fine on newly created events, but not the the already fetched events from the server.

```
    const handleDelete = () => {
      try {
        deleteAvailability(e.event.id)
        setModalContent({ title: '', content: '', visible: false })
        calendarRef.current.getApi().getEventById(e.event.id).remove()
        calendarRef.current.getApi().refetchEvents()
        } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
 


<FullCalendar
        nowIndicator
        plugins={[momentTimezonePlugin, timeGridPlugin, dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        initialView="timeGridWeek"
        headerToolbar={{
          left: 'prev,next today goToDate refreshEvents',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'showWeekends,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
        }}
        customButtons={{
          goToDate: {
            text: 'Pick Date',
            click: (e) => GoToDate(e),
          }
        }}
        ref={calendarRef}
        editable
        selectable
        selectMirror
        select={handleEventAdd}
        eventsSet={(e) => onsetEvents(e)}
        eventClick={(e) => handleEventUpdateAndDelete(e)}
        eventSources={[currentevents]}
        eventDrop={(e) => handleupdateSchedule(e)}
        dayCellContent={injectDayCellContent}
        weekNumberContent={weekRender}
      />
```

Notes: I am also tagging angular and vue in the questions even when it is not related because I think these issues are already there with these frameworks. So I could use your feedback aswell, Thank you :)

**FetchEvents Function**

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const { searchEvents: myEvents } = await searchEvents()
    try {
      const data = myEvents.content.forEach((x) => {
        x.start = new Date(x.start)
        x.end = new Date(x.end)
      })
      setIsPageLoaded(true)
      calendarRef.current.getApi().addEventSource(data)
      return clonedata
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    return true
  }
```

Comment: Could you please try rendering the calendar again after these actions ?

Comment: Yes I have tried it, you can see the below in the code. It works all the time, except the first time. I have console logged and I can see that I am getting the calendarRef also...   calendarRef.current.getApi().refetchEvents()

Comment: `refetchEvents()` only works if you define a dynamic event source to begin with. Obviously I can't see the content of `currentEvents` but I'm guessing it's probably a static array of events. Therefore, fullCalendar cannot refetch the events because it doesn't know where to fetch them from - all it received was an initial list of events. Once those are passed in, it does not know where they came from or how to get any more.

Comment: You can create a dynamic event source in one of two ways 1) pass in a URL which fullCalendar calls (via AJAX) and which returns a suitable JSON array direct to the calendar - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed, 2) pass in a reference to a callback function, within which you write some code which fetches the events by whatever method you wish and returns them to fullCalendar - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function. Both of these will be called repeatedly by fullCalendar - whenever you call refetchEvents, and/or whenever the calendar's date range changes.

Comment: Awesome info! Thanks @ADyson

Comment: No worries, but it's all there in the documenation already :-)

Comment: Hey @ADyson, How would I write an Events as a function as they mentioned in the documentation, I have updated the question, you can see that my fetchData function only returns the array, how would I write it so that I can provide a success callback and failure callback?

Comment: The callbacks etc are supplied by fullCalendar as arguments to the function. So you need to start by defining arguments that the function accepts, so you can use them within it... E.g. `const fetchData = async(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) => {`

Comment: That is great it worked! Now I am able to use refetch.  I will update the answer here soon, Thanks :)  You have been of great help, Now I've got a full working calendar :) Just one small issue remains tho, the dayHeaderContent injection hook does not load until I click an event or change the view or interact with calendar somehow, How would I make it render every time the calendar loads, or event is changed etc.. I am using the dayHeaderContent to calculate the total events duration and show it on top.

Comment: I haven't tested but t's probably that it _does_ run when the calendar loads, but of course the events are loaded asynchronously so at that moment there aren't yet any events to count - they arrive a little bit later

Comment: Yes that is exactly the case, When I provide as a static list, it works. So what are my options now, how do I trigger the content injection hook whenever the event is dragged or updated. I think I can refresh the calendar, destroy it and re render is that a good option?

Comment: Can you simply call the calendar.render() function? Sorry I don't have time to test anything right now